# Handling Nested Option Types in StorageDoubleMap::iter_prefix Method

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, storage

I am building a Substrate pallet where I have a storage item defined as a `StorageDoubleMap:`

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::unbounded]
#[pallet::getter(fn labels)]
pub(super) type Labels<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
    _,
    Twox64Concat,
    HashId<T>,
    Twox64Concat,
    AccountOf<T>,
    LabelsDetail<T>,
    OptionQuery,
>;
```

I need to retrieve data from this storage map by using only the first key `(label_id)`, and then perform some operations like inserting it into another storage item and emitting an event.

I've tried using the iter_prefix method, but I'm having trouble handling the nested Option types it returns. Here's my function:

```
  pub fn verify_labels(label_id: &HashId<T>) -> DispatchResult {
    let label_info = Labels::<T>::iter_prefix(&label_id).next().ok_or("Label not found")?;
    match label_info {
        Some(value) => {
            VerifiedLabels::<T>::insert(&label_id, &value.owner, &value);
        },
        None => {},
    };
    Self::deposit_event(Event::LabelsVeryfied {
        label_id: label_info.label_id,
        owner: label_info.owner.clone(),
    });
    Ok(())
}
```

I'm getting a type mismatch error:

> mismatched types
> expected tuple (::AccountId, LabelInfo<::AccountId, ::Hash>)
> found enum std::option::Option<_>

**How can I correctly handle the nested Option types to fix this error?**

Answer (score 1):

You have already unwrapped `label_info` with [`.ok_or()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or):

> Transforms the Option into a Result<T, E>.

Then followed by `?` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/result/question_mark.html)), which unwraps `Ok()` or errors when finding `Err()`. So now you have your tuple which is stated in the error message:

> expected tuple (::AccountId, LabelInfo<::AccountId, ::Hash>)

Try:

```
let label_info = Labels::<T>::iter_prefix(&label_id).next().ok_or("Label not found")?;
VerifiedLabels::<T>::insert(&label_id, &label_info.owner, &label_info);
Self::deposit_event(Event::LabelsVeryfied {
    label_id: label_info.label_id,
    owner: label_info.owner.clone(),
});
Ok(())
```

Comment: it show me this error 

the trait bound `&(<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, LabelInfo<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>): EncodeLike<LabelInfo<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `EncodeLike<T>`:
  <() as EncodeLike>

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8431/the-trait-bound-vecu8-encodelikeu32-is-not-satisfied?